# tokenize a string in c

Tags: c, string, tokenize

How can I tokenize strings like this in c:

```
char str1[] = " property :: content | label ";
char str2[] = "property::content";
char str3[] = "content";
```

[edit]

I have tried the folowwing:

```
char str[] = " property :: content | label ";
char *property, *content, *label;

property = strtok(str, "::");
content = strtok(NULL, "|");
label = strtok(NULL, "|");

printf ("%s %s %s\n", property, content, label);
```

but it splits strings according to a char so it would work for the pipe character used to delimit labels. However the "::" delimiter is a string, not a char. I don't know how to deal with it.

[edit 2]

I also have this code:

```
char sentence [] = "property :: content | label";
char property [30];
char content [30];
char label [30];

sscanf (sentence, "%s :: %s | %s", property, content, label);
printf ("<span property=\"%s\" content=\"%s\">%s</span>\n", property, content, label);
```

I'm just wondering how I can dynamically set the size of each char array...

Thanks.

Comment: You can try `strtok` or `sscanf`.

Comment: Or for more hardcore tokenizing, try `flex`

Comment: @cnicutar: thanks. strtok splits according to a char so it would work for the pipe character used to delimit labels. However "::" is a string. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: @user1415785 - [Try something](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and if it doesn't work, show us what you've tried and why it doesn't work.  Again, we're not your personal research assistants.  Put forth some effort.

Comment: @user1415785 In your example, you've surrounded all the punctuation marks with whitespace. So passing `" "` as the `sep` argument of `strtok` would work, *for the examples*. We can't guess what the grammar really is, you need to tell us.

Comment: Maybe this can help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366028/what-is-a-good-c-c-css-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a basic [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)

The best way to know it is to pick up a compiler book and read on that.

In short, you would need a bunch of [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex) and start matching your strings against the regular expressions until you find the biggest matching one with its corresponding dfa in a final state.

Alternatively, if every token is separated by space, you can simply use `strtok` and `strcmp` to distinguish between special words (such as `::`) and the rest of the input.

After the lexical analysis is done, you'd need a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser). I don't know your application, so your parser could turn out to be really simple, but otherwise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403647/parsing-strings-of-equations-in-c-using-scanf/7404179#7404179) might help you kick off.